# ReactJS components in same bundle across different pages

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to have multiple ReactJS components in the same bundle but would only want specific components to be loaded on specific pages.

Components I have:
1. Search - include search bar, search results with pagination, and filter
2. Profile form (multi page in wizard format)

Obviously I want the Search Components to be included on only the search page and Profile component on the profile page. And for performance and optimization reason I want everything in the same bundle (using grunt and browserify). I have the renders like the following in one of my files:

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');

var Search = require('./Search');
var Profile = require('./Profile');

ReactDOM.render(
  React.createElement(Profile, null),
  document.getElementById('reactWrapperProfile')
);
ReactDOM.render(
  React.createElement(Search, null),
  document.getElementById('reactWrapperSearch')
);
```

Then I realized that both reactWrapperProfile and reactWrapperSearch will have to be created across multiple pages or else it would throw:

```
Uncaught Invariant Violation: _registerComponent(...): Target container is not a DOM element.
```

It would not be ideal to have all components rendered and use css to hide them. What's the best practice or solution for scenario like this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to have a website with multiple pages, I would recommend you [react-router](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router). You can find multiple examples in the repository to show how it works. Your index (bundle index) file will look then for example like this:

```
// ...
ReactDOM.render((
<Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
      <Route path="search" component={Search}/>
      <Route path="profile" component={Profile}/>
    </Route>
  </Router>
), document.body);
```

If you try google, you can also find a lot of tutorials for "react router tutorial".

Hope this helps.

Best regards